# Are there best practices about data lifecycle management involving citizens?

Tags: releasing-data, best-practice

Different data portals from different countries treat feedback about datasets (i.e., errors, annotations, comments) differently, but none seems to consider feedback towards the citizens.

Are there some best practices? which ones? are they documented?

Comment: Could you say a little more about what you mean by "feedback towards the citizens"?

Comment: The simplest example: I find an typo in a dataset. I report it, say, via email. Nothing happens. I would think people in charge of data portals have faced (and hopefully solved and documented!) these types of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Data.gov we have a several different ways for people to provide feedback, most of which are publicly viewable.

- [Suggest a new dataset](https://explore.data.gov/nominate) and see what others have suggested (all the dataset suggestions are tracked to completion, although not all requested datasets exist or can be released)
- Comment on or rate a dataset (see an [example](https://explore.data.gov/Geography-and-Environment/Worldwide-M1-Earthquakes-Past-7-Days/7tag-iwnu) for earthquake data)
- Ask a question in our [Developer's Community](http://www.data.gov/developers/community/developers/forums) (these are moderated for spam)
- Send an [email](http://www.data.gov/contact-us)
- Host or participate in events (see a listing on our [community page](http://www.data.gov/communities))

(Disclaimer:  I serve as the Evangelist for Data.gov)